# Fan Control in Windows on a Retina Macbook Pro (Boot Camp)

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, cooling

Gaming on the rMBP under Windows 7 is a very good experience but I have noticed that unless I elevate the chassis there is a tendency for the automatically regulated fan speed to fail to engage a rising computational load fast enough to keep the CPU under thermal shutdown temperature (Tj max) and freeze the machine.

This is somewhat inconvenient of course, as it means the CPU has reached a temperature that it should never reach, and also requires a reboot.

I know that the fans are capable of running higher than the highest they have been recorded to run which is in the neighborhood of 4900 RPM, they should be capable of going to 6000 RPM, which, even though it would be noisy would be keeping the CPU cooler, which is a good thing in my book.

Here's a screen capture to illustrate...

[image]

So I hope this makes it clear that Apple's fan speed scaling is a bit on the conservative side when the temperatures are high.

From what I can tell, once you get the machine nice and toasty and the load "stabilizes" it will generally be in a state of equilibrium where the CPU core temperatures hover in the high 80's and 90 degrees C, making occasional excursions above 100 degrees C. So long as the 105 degree Tj Max point is not passed the computer keeps up with whatever game you're playing just fine.

My understanding is that under OS X I can use the smcFanControl app to manually specify the fan RPMs, but I have not been able to find a similar way to control or fix the fan speed once I am booted into Windows. When I did this sort of experimenting on my Macbook Air there seemed to be a method which involved setting the desired setting in smcFanControl in OS X and then sometimes rebooting into windows would have the setting stick. This would basically get the job done if it works on the rMBP as well, but I'd prefer something friendlier.

Are there any fan control applications for Windows that will recognize and allow control of the Macbook Pro fans?

Answer (score 22):

I wonder why noone mentioned wonderful and **free** [Macs Fan Control app](http://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) that works flawlessly on Windows. All mac hardware support is declared, [OS X](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/47386/macs-fan-control) version is also available.

Comment: Thank you. This needs more up-votes. Works WAY better than Lubbos on my late 2008 MBP

Comment: Just be aware that I have seen this app just start chewing CPU like there's no tomorrow once I boot into my bootcamp partition from Parallels. Otherwise, yes it does seem to function well when doing the whole gaming-on-a-macbook-from-windows thing

Comment: **Steven Lu**, The app doesn't work in Parallels, only real Windows installed  on a separate partition

Comment: I use the Windows partition in both ways. Most often booting into it with Parallels to test something in a browser on Windows... Playing games on a laptop is silly :)

Comment: This tool can be complicated to set up, average user has NO IDEA which temp. sensor should he use for "right fan" etc.

Comment: Guess it's true, this tool is for an advanced user.

Comment: I always simply max the fan out. It appears Macs Fan Control supports windows, I assume it will generally make your mac faster while running in bootcamp, otherwise, what's the point. With parallels, Macs Fan Control has a Mac version. Should use the native mac version when running macOS to speed up everything (including parallels). But, bootcamp offers even more perf when using windows.

Comment: While the free version has some usability, the options are basic. No curve settings just min and max and it changes RPM as it sees fit, and you can't save your settings. Pro isn't expensive (the ironic thing is Macs are expensive, you'd think they did better cooling, I digress)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use an external application to control fan speed in an smart way. "Lubbo's MacBook Pro Fan Control" is the best option to use:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/lubbofancontrol/

Don't forget, in order to have smart control on fans speed, just change the value of "CPU Key" to "TC0F". Then restart the application.

Place a shortcut of this application on your Windows startup and that's all!

Your Mac will stay cool and keep running even under heavy loads.

Comment: Wow I wonder why I haven't found this earlier. Thanks! I hope it supports my machine, I'll test it next time I boot to Windows (won't be for some time)

Comment: On my late 2013 rMBP running Win8.1, Lubbo's doesn't seem to read the temperatures correctly: it claims just about everything is at 90°C, which is pretty damn hot. Macs Fan Control reads out more reasonable temperatures, and the two I was able to read with a generic Windows temperature utility are in agreement. I think the issue may be that Lubbo's hasn't been updated in a long time, and the hardware is no longer compatible.

Answer (score 4):

So I went with the lubbo fancontrol and changed the config option as suggested above.

I'm running windows 7 pro on my macbook pro retina late 2012, 2.6 i7.

One thing you can do regardless of an extra fan controller is drop the CPU power.

Go to Power Options > Change plan settings (starting from Balanced) > Change Advanced power settings.

Then in the Power Options popup window, I went to: Processor power management > Maximum processor state, and set my On battery and Plugged in percentages to 90%.

Got a bout a 20 deg C drop in temperature. I posted about it here:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=20685544&postcount=12

Comment: This is really interesting. I'll have to look into what this power setting actually does -- It seems very useful if it's possible to reduce the active cpu power by 10% while reducing power consumption and heat by a significantly greater fraction. Maybe it is able to engage the Intel Turbo Boost in an intelligent way to yield these results.

Comment: This did the trick for me. My machine is running no where near as hot as before and the fans are finally silent. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out! As an update: I was able to set the processor state to 95% and still keep the temp low. Play around with it to get balance of power/heat/fanspeed.

Comment: Mid 2015 MBP with ATI here - tried different settings and 90% max cpu + ATI PowerPlay to "maximize battery life" silences fans to a whisper. Thank you!

Comment: this worked for me, setting the maximum processor state to 90% solved the issue

Comment: Also applies to Windows 10